# When i set div position absolute then below div come upon it why this happen?

Tags: css

When i set div position absolute then below div come upon it why this happen? on small screen the button comes upon the div why this happen, and also i want that in small mobile screen the div box width to full browser screen

```css
.qa-part-q-view {
 border-radius:5px;
border: solid #EBF2F7;
min-height:70px; 
align-items:left; 
padding:10px;10px; 
margin: 10px 10px;}  

/* On screens that are 992px or less, set the background color to blue */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
.qa-part-q-view {
content: " ";
 z-index: -1;
 
border: 2px solid #EBF2F7; 
 }

/* On screens that are 600px or less, set the background color to olive */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.qa-part-q-view {
content: " ";
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
border: 0 none #ccc;
border-bottom: 5px solid #EBF2F7;
border-top: 5px solid #EBF2F7;
border-radius: 0;
padding:10px;10px; 
 margin: 0;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="qa-part-q-view"><p>jjjjjjjjjj</p> </div>
 <button>kkkfkf</button>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. After that edit your question and provide a [repro] as debugging details!

Answer (score 0):

Related to the button-width:
css:

```
.qa-part-q-view {
 border-radius:5px;
border: solid #EBF2F7;
min-height:70px; 
align-items:left; 
padding:10px;10px; 
margin: 10px 10px;}  

/* On screens that are 992px or less, set the background color to blue */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
.qa-part-q-view {
content: " ";
 z-index: -1;
 
border: 2px solid #EBF2F7; 
 }
}

/* On screens that are 600px or less, set the background color to olive */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.qa-part-q-view {
content: " ";
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
border: 0 none #ccc;
border-bottom: 5px solid #EBF2F7;
border-top: 5px solid #EBF2F7;
border-radius: 0;
padding:10px;10px; 
 margin: 0;
 }
}

button {
width: 100vw;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="qa-part-q-view"><p>jjjjjjjjjj</p> </div>
 <button>kkkfkf</button>
```

my result:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufmcl.png)

Comment: I appreciate you bro, but my problem is with small screen when you see this result in small screen the problem is occurred please help me and if you interested then please try again with small screens. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set the box with equal to the browser screen-width, use:

```
width: 100vw;
```

Comment: i try this but not work

Comment: Maybe because you didn't close the media query 
"@media screen and (max-width: 992px)"